# Python inheritance change attribute type

Tags: python, inheritance, scikit-learn

I am trying to build a class that inherits a class from sklearn

```
class my_lasso(linear_model.Lasso):

    def __init__(self, alpha=1.0, fit_intercept=True, normalize=False,
                 precompute=False, copy_X=True, max_iter=1000, tol=1e-4,
                 warm_start=False, positive=False, random_state=None,
                 selection='cyclic'):
        super(my_lasso, self).__init__(
                alpha=alpha, fit_intercept=fit_intercept,
                normalize=normalize, precompute=precompute, copy_X=copy_X,
                max_iter=max_iter, tol=tol, warm_start=warm_start,
                positive=positive, random_state=random_state,
                selection=selection)

    def fit(self, x, y):
        super(my_lasso, self).fit(x, y)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.residus = self.y - self.predict(self.x)
        self.r2 = self.score(self.x, self.y)
        self.error = np.linalg.norm(self.residus) ** 2
        self.support = np.zeros(x.shape[1])
        self.support[self.coef_ != 0] = 1
```

What I don't understand is that when I test my class it changes the attribute `intercept_` to an array

```
In [5]: testlasso.intercept_
Out[5]: array([ 23.44591837])
```

same when I am trying to inherit from LinearRegression.
My coefs are now double arrays

```
In [7]: testls.coef_
Out[7]: 
array([[-0.56194996,  0.80247616, -0.0150445 , -5.76399971,  0.23495704,
     2.77166415]])
```

Any hints?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

First, if you're not overriding the constructor then you don't need the block.

Your code is fine. The shape of `intercept_` and `coef_` are determined from the [number of targets](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/linear_model/coordinate_descent.py#L868) which is 2.

Comment: Thx ! was passing y as a 2D matric, now its works fine.
what do you mean by
"if you're not overriding the constructor then you don't need the block."

Comment: Thank you. I meant to say that you can lose the `__init__` method since you're not overriding it.